# Replacing Block Windows Mortared In Brick Veneer

Tags: basement, windows, brick, masonry, basement-refinishing

I've got 3 basement block windows to replace with vented block windows and need some help on a way to handle this that will leave me with a decent end result.

The block windows were installed in the brick veneer instead of the foundation, and the size of the windows are bigger than the foundation's rough opening. For example, when outside looking into the windows, you can see the sill plate blocking a portion of the window.

When looking at the windows from inside the basement, the sill plate blocks the top of the window. And when looking inbetween the sill plate and top of the window, you will see the brick lintel.

[image: block window]

[image: block window]

So here's where I need help:

The driveway area will be gone (doing excavation work as well) so I can remove the window and install a new one into the foundation (easy). However, I'll be left with an opening in the brick veneer that's way too big.

I can't think of a way to reduce the opening in the brick veneer that won't look bad.

Another row of brick will make the opening too small.

I could replace the block window with a vinyl window in the foundation and trim it like crazy but I don't see that ending well.

Anybody have ideas or experience with this?

This is my first time ever seeing a basement window set like this and it's not making sense to me why it would be installed big enough to see the sill plate through the window.

Comment: If you are considering vinyl windows, they can be made any size to fit your opening. They can even be flangeless, as in no nail holes around the perimeter, although I would still keep the nail flange to tie in the weatherproofing. On the west coast they are priced by the size in inches, all are made to order, whether it is a standard size or custom.

Comment: @Jack I'd like to stick with glass block but will choose vinyl if fixing the current window installation with glass block will result in an ugly-looking final product. Replacing with glass block will require me to reduce the brick veneer's opening and I'm looking for ways to make that look good/decent in this retrofit.